# Figure out Indexing error in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, indexing

I am using ES 1.x version and having trouble to find the errors while indexing some document.

Some documents are not getting indexed and all I saw is below lines in ES logs.

```
stop throttling indexing: numMergesInFlight=2, maxNumMerges=3

now throttling indexing: numMergesInFlight=4, maxNumMerges=3
```

I did a quick google and understood the high level of these errors but would like to understand below:

1. Will  ES retry the documents which were throttled?
2. Is there is any way to know the documents which were throttled by enabling some detailed logging and if yes, then in which classes?
3. I don't see any error message, apart from above `INFO` logs. Is there is a way to enable verbose logging for indexing which shows what exactly is going on during indexing?

Comment: This is probably the origin of your issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6066
I would definitely upgrade to a more recent version, 1.x has been EOL for more than two years now.

Comment: Have you tried on a more recent version of ES?

Comment: @Val , I don't have option to move to newer version of ES

Comment: You'll have to think about it, though, because you might end up into big troubles at some point with no support whatsoever. Also the latest versions are much more performant and optimized.

Comment: I agree, but have some scale challenges and without addressing them we can't move forward. also, latest version has lots of breaking changes, so we need to address them as well.

Comment: ok, anyway, the throttling is not about documents it's about segment files. As described in the ticket I linked to, Lucene can't keep up with the segment merging when you're throwing too much data at ES. You can try to increase the logging level to TRACE for `org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine`

Answer (score 2):

The throttling messages you see in the logs are not the issue. throttling is happening in the background in order for elasticsearch to protect against segments explosion. see explanation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#segments-and-merging

The throttling does not drop messages, but just slows down indexing, which cause a back pressure to the indexers and external queues.

When indexing fail you should get an error response for the index/bulk request. in order to tell what is the issue you should inspect the responses ES provide for the index/bulk requests. Logs might not tell the full story, as it depends on the log level configuration, which is per module in ES.

Another option is that you are able to index, but the logs don't have the timestamp you think it does. check [_cat/indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) in order to see if the docs count increases when you index. if the doc counts increases it means that the indexed docs are there, and you need to refine your searches.

Comment: thanks but I am searching docs with their UID and not on the timestamp, hence I am sure that these documents are not indexed. `When indexing fail you should get an error response for the index/bulk request` these how can I figure out ?

Comment: How do you index the logs? Do you use logstash? If so then you might need to turn on debugging in logstash. Another option is to configure elasticsearch DEBUG log level on the data nodes. One more option is to try to index the docs manually using curl or postman, this way you'll see the full response

Comment: As I mentioned in previous comment elad answer I don't use logstash and index it from application using jest client. Can you tell which specific log I  need to enable on data node and manually it wouldn't be reproducible as it happends when we are indexing large data.

Comment: as you use jest, you can print errors in your application as well. in ES, from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/logging.html "You could modify the logging.yml file and restart your nodes—but that is both tedious and leads to unnecessary downtime. Instead, you can update logging levels through the cluster-settings API". I suggest you'll start by changing root log level, then when you see the exceptions you can narrow it to the exception package: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-logging-secrets.

Comment: If you are using bulk index, you might get 200ok response, but some of the items in the bulk might still fail. You need to go over the items responses array and check them one by one, you might see the error you are looking for there

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch does not do retries to the best of my knowledge, that is up to the client (though i havent used 1.x in quite some time)
logstash, for example, retries batches it gets 503 and 429 on exactly for these kinds of reasons https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb#L55

Comment: Is there is any way to enable the verbose logging for indexing, As I don't see 429 error on ES logs.. also how to determine in a batch which doc is indexing and which is throttled ?

Comment: you can see the behaviour logstash uses in the link i added above

Comment: what i meant was, that you can read the code logstash has and mimic the same behaviour in what ever code/tool you are using